# YAML data sequence problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I need to have correct order of values inside Ruby array after parsing YAML file.

I have this simple example showing my issue:

```
x = "columns:\n  col_1 : ~\n  col_2 : ~\n  col_3 : ~\n  col4 : ~"
s = YAML::load(x)
```

console output gives :

> x = "columns:\n  col_1 : ~\n  col_2 : ~\n  col_3 : ~\n  col4 : ~"
>   => "columns:\n  col_1 : ~\n  col_2 : ~\n  col_3 : ~\n  col4 : ~"
>   s = YAML::load(x)
>   => {"columns"=>{"col_3"=>nil, "col4"=>nil, "col_1"=>nil, "col_2"=>nil}}

"columns" array is in different sequence as it was in input data :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're building a map not a array here. As fare as I do remember list syntax is:

```
columns:  
- col_1 : ~
- col_2 : ~
- col_3 : ~
- col_4 : ~
```

This will result in a map {"columns"=> [{"col_1"=>nil},{"col_2"=>nil}, {"col_3"=>nil}, {"col4"=>nil}] I suppose (did not test it).

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right. Have to study more YAML specs :)